# Scrapy pipeline error cannot import name

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python programming and using scrapy. I have setup my crawler and so far it was working until I got to the point where I wanted to figure out how to download images. The error I am getting is cannot import name NsiscrapePipeline. I dont know what I am doing wrong and I dont understand some of the documentation as I am new. Please help

Items File

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class NsiscrapeItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = Field()
    location = Field()
    stock_number = Field()
    year = Field()
    manufacturer = Field()
    model = Field()
    length = Field()
    price = Field()
    status = Field()
    url = Field()

    pass
```

Spider

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from NSIscrape.items import NsiscrapeItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import NsiscrapePipeline
import Image

class NsiscrapeSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "Nsiscrape"
    allowed_domain = ["yachtauctions.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.yachtauctions.com/inventory/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//tr')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
    item = NsiscrapeItem()
    item['location'] = site.select('td[2]/text()').extract()
    item['stock_number'] = site.select('td[3]/a/text()').extract()
    item['year'] = site.select('td[4]/text()').extract()
    item['manufacturer'] = site.select('td[5]/text()').extract()
    item['model'] = site.select('td[6]/text()').extract()
    item['length'] = site.select('td[7]/text()').extract()
    item['price'] = site.select('td[8]/text()').extract()
    item['status'] = site.select('td[10]/img/@src').extract()
    item['url'] = site.select('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
    item['image_urls'] = site.select('td/a[3]/img/@data-original').extract()
        item['images'] = item['image_urls']
        yield Request(item['url'][0], meta={'item':item}, callback=self.product_detail_page)


    def product_detail_page(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    #add all images url in the item['image_urls']
    yield item
```

settings

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.image.NsiscrapePipeline']
IMAGES_STORE = 'c:\Python27\NSIscrape\IMG'
IMAGES_EXPIRES = 90
```

Pipelines This is where I am unsure if I am missing something

```
from scrapy.item import Item 

class NsiscrapePipeline(Item):
image_urls = Field()
    images = Field()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

error

```
File "NSIscrape\spiders\NSI_Spider.py", line 9, in <module>
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import NsiscrapePipeline
ImportError: cannot import name NsiscrapePipeline
```

Comment: is spider the same as NSI_Spider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres my final code thats working. There was two issues

1: I was missing the second backslash that needede to be in the request --> //td[1]/a[3]/img/@data-original

2: I had to check the full URL in which the image would be displayed and join them together which was the main URL or the allowed URL and the image URL.

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    images = hxs.select('//tr')
    url = []
    for image in images:
        urls = NsiscrapeItem()
        urls['image_urls'] = ["http://www.yachtauctions.com" +  x for x in image.select('//td[1]/a[3]/img/@data-original').extract()]
        url.append(urls)
    return url
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't part of the library :) - at least by looking at their current [master branch](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/images.py)

I think you're looking for `ImagesPipeline`

Their example may help! [example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html)

p.s. I don't think you custom name the class - at least not by how scapy is designed; i'm reasonably sure you use their class ;)

---

Comment: Thank you thats exactly what my issue was.

Comment: I am getting a new error now would you happen to know why? raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type
(url).__name__) exceptions.TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got list:

Comment: uhm you tried to give a list instead of a string to whatever generated that. as in you tried to type ['http://stuff.com'] in chrome for example and it got confused because it doesn't know what to do with that

Comment: How do I give it a string? I mean it is more than 1 url I am grabbing from the item['url']. Is that the issue?

Comment: it probably just wants the url? sorry I don't have context for the function. Some of them take arguments like get or post args I think

Comment: Okay thank you for all your help I will try to post this in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to pass list, but this function accepts only string. Pass only one element from list (for example list[0]).

Comment: @I have changed my code to Request(['url'][0], and I am getting the following error: raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: url. I dont understand what this means and I have tried changing the code to item[0], 'url'[0], and even changing the index number from 0 to 1 or 2 but that method gave me an index error.

Comment: I guess my real question is how do I pass it?

Comment: I just figured out its coming from this line: item['images'] = site.select('td/a[3]/img/@data-original').extract() I am thinking I am missing something. @solusipse

Comment: Heres the exact error  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.16.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 61, in _set_url raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url) exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:/images/photos/8940/wide_8940__0.jpg @solusipse